# How to make SELECT... WHERE IN work for AND and not only OR?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables:

```
blog_posts // Contains blog posts
blog_tags // Contains tags
rel__blog_post_tags // Relates tags to a blog post (refering relation IDs)
```

This is my PHP code:

```
// I get tags from URL: /tag/tag1;tag2;tag3
$tags = explode(';', $options['req_tags']);
// Prepare for prepared SQL query
$in = str_repeat('?,', count($tags) - 1) . '?';
// Prepare SQL param array as I need to mix category ID with tags...
$sql_params = $tags;

// This SQL will select with IN (equals to OR but want to change to AND)
$sql_get_posts = '
    SELECT * FROM blog_posts
    WHERE category_id = ?
    AND post_id IN
        (SELECT post_id FROM rel__blog_post_tags
            WHERE tag_id IN (' . $in . '));';

// Prepare the query
$get_posts = $PDO->prepare($sql_get_posts);
// Add category ID to beginning of array of SQL params (in front of tags)
array_unshift($sql_params, $options['category_id']);

// Now execute and get blog posts to array
$get_posts->execute($sql_params);
$postdata = $get_posts->fetchAll();

?>
```

OK so my problem here is that I use "WHERE tag_id IN...". This will return any blog posts that matches:

```
...AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM rel__blog_post_tags WHERE tag_id='tag1' OR tag_id='tag2' OR tag_id='tag3'... and so on.
```

So basically, I cannot narrow down my blog post results by adding more tags, which is what I am after.

How can I change this SQL query to make it so that it will be like the below, so that if I have a blog post with ID "foobar" and it has a connection with tag1 and tag2 in the database it will not show up, as I am looking for blog post with ID "foobar" that has tag tag1, tag2 AND tag3:

```
...AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM rel__blog_post_tags WHERE tag_id='tag1' AND tag_id='tag2' AND tag_id='tag3'... And so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by creating the set of "and tag_id=?" string  using for loop.
Like shown below:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($tags);$++){
if($i=0){
$condition="tag_id=$tags[$i]";
}
else{
$condition.="and tag_id=$tags[$i]";
}

}
```

Comment: This was my own solution to the problem, I was hoping there would be a one line solution like the IN () but now I know and thanks for the code =)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is that the select statement is analyzing each row. A single row can only have one value for tag_id. When you are using AND you are checking to see if the tag_id for that row is equal to multiple values which can never be true.

In a real-world example, I cannot both be wearing shoes AND boots at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post based on this question, http://www.kurungkurawal.com/2015/03/23/sql-filter-data-berdasarkan-beberapa-baris-data/ but it is in Bahasa Indonesia.

Basically (based on my example)

1. Collect the tid of desired tag
2. Get all the posts that contains the tag(s), as you use with `SELECT ... WHERE IN (...)` make sure it doesn't contain duplicate row, you can prevent it by using primary key on both field, or use `distinct`
3. Count occurance of each pid
4. filter by using `having` on pid that have number of occurance equal on number of tags we are filtering.

Sorry if my explanation is not crystal clear. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried to make this work by reading your post with Google Translate (even though I do know some Indonesian like: Lima (five?) :) as I have been there once). Anyway..

It works by means of returning a post_id and tag_id and COUNT. But I want to return ALL blog post data...

How can I get all data for the post in to the result rather than just post_id and tag_id and count?

Comment: you can select all the post field by filtering the id. something like `select * from ppost where pid in ( the previous large query )` or by `join` or even by looping from PHP for each row of post id.